# Extract city names from large text with R

Tags: r, extract

Hello i have an intriguing question here. Suppose that i have a long character which includes city names between others.

```
test<-"Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA|Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA|Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Dana Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Washington University, Saint Louis, Missouri, USA|Mount SInai Medical Center, New York, New York, USA|Memorial Sloan Kettering Cancer Center, New York, New York, USA|Carolinas Healthcare System, Charlotte, North Carolina, USA|University Hospitals Case Medical Center; Seidman Cancer Center, Cleveland, Ohio, USA|Vanderbilt University Medical Center, Nashville, Tennessee, USA|Seattle Cancer Care Alliance, Seattle, Washington, USA|National Cancer Center, Gyeonggi-do, Korea, Republic of|Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Korea University Guro Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Asan Medical Center., Seoul, Korea, Republic of|VU MEDISCH CENTRUM; Dept. of Medical Oncology"
```

My goal is to extract all the city names of it. And I achieved it by following five steps.

```
   #replace | with ,
   test2<-str_replace_all(test, "[|]", ", ")

   # Remove punctuation from data
   test3<-gsub("[[:punct:]\n]","",test2)

   # Split data at word boundaries
   test4 <- strsplit(test3, " ")

   # Load data from package maps
   data(world.cities)

   # Match on cities in world.cities
   citiestest<-lapply(test4, function(x)x[which(x %in% world.cities$name)])
```

The result may be correct

```
citiestest
[[1]]
 [1] "San"        "Boston"     "Boston"     "Washington" "York"      
 [6] "York"       "Kettering"  "York"       "York"       "Charlotte" 
[11] "Carolina"   "Cleveland"  "Nashville"  "Seattle"    "Seattle"   
[16] "Washington" "Asan"
```

But as you can see I cannot deal with cities with two-words name (New York, San Diego etc.) as they are separated. Of course fix this issue manually is not an option as my real dataset is quite large.

Comment: Do some queries for named entity extraction & nlp (play with the keywords a bit to tune the results). This is a perfect use-case for it if you can find models trained with this type of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way that works with no loop

```
pat="(,.\\w+,)|(,.\\w+.\\w+,)"
gsub("(,\\s)|,","",regmatches(m<-strsplit(test,"\\|")[[1]],regexpr(pat,m)))

[1] "San Diego"   "New Haven"   "Boston"      "Boston"      "Saint Louis" "New York"    "New York"   
[8] "Charlotte"   "Cleveland"   "Nashville"   "Seattle"     "Gyeonggi-do" "Seoul"       "Seoul"      
[15] "Seoul"       "Seoul"
```

The other results given in this page do fail: for example, there is a town called `Greonggi-do` This is not given in the other solutions. Also some of the codes give the whole string as the town

Comment: My solution certainly finds the town `Greonggi-do`.

Comment: yours does but under  `Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea, Republic of ` it gives  `"Yonsei University Health System"` as the city which is not correct

Comment: If the position of the city is not known/is variable, then regex is not so suitable for this.  In this case, the OP should provide logic for such edge cases.

Comment: Well that seems the challenge here. Yet as you can see the one I gave did find `Seoul` as the city. So it is still possible

Comment: Interesting approach. From what i can understand it works with the position of the word. Could you explain me how you define this position in your code?

Comment: I would like to do the same with the states

Comment: I cant remember how i wrote this. Maybe if I go back to the code and look at it. One issue though is that if the name of the city is not found, the regexp returns a `character(0)` which technically will shift the results. eg. If there was another row say 18 and the row had a city name, then that will be given as result 17 instead of 18 since row 17 is null(has no name)

Answer (score 4):

A rather different approach which may be more or less useful, depending on the data at hand: Pass each address to a geocoding API, then pull the city out of the response.

```
library(tidyverse)

places <- data_frame(string = "Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA|Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA|Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Dana Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Washington University, Saint Louis, Missouri, USA|Mount SInai Medical Center, New York, New York, USA|Memorial Sloan Kettering Cancer Center, New York, New York, USA|Carolinas Healthcare System, Charlotte, North Carolina, USA|University Hospitals Case Medical Center; Seidman Cancer Center, Cleveland, Ohio, USA|Vanderbilt University Medical Center, Nashville, Tennessee, USA|Seattle Cancer Care Alliance, Seattle, Washington, USA|National Cancer Center, Gyeonggi-do, Korea, Republic of|Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Korea University Guro Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Asan Medical Center., Seoul, Korea, Republic of|VU MEDISCH CENTRUM; Dept. of Medical Oncology") %>% 
    separate_rows(string, sep = '\\|')

places <- places %>% 
    mutate(geodata = map(string, ~{Sys.sleep(1); ggmap::geocode(.x, output = 'all')}))

places <- places %>% 
    mutate(address_components = map(geodata, list('results', 1, 'address_components')),
           address_components = map(address_components, 
                                    ~as_data_frame(transpose(.x)) %>% 
                                        unnest(long_name, short_name)),
           city = map(address_components, unnest),
           city = map_chr(city, ~{
               l <- set_names(.x$long_name, .x$types); 
               coalesce(l['locality'], l['administrative_area_level_1'])
           }))
```

Comparing the result and the original,

```
places %>% select(city, string)
#> # A tibble: 17 x 2
#>    city       string                                                                               
#>    <chr>      <chr>                                                                                
#>  1 San Diego  Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA                                      
#>  2 New Haven  Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA                                      
#>  3 Boston     Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA                          
#>  4 Boston     Dana Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, Massachusetts, USA                             
#>  5 St. Louis  Washington University, Saint Louis, Missouri, USA                                    
#>  6 New York   Mount SInai Medical Center, New York, New York, USA                                  
#>  7 New York   Memorial Sloan Kettering Cancer Center, New York, New York, USA                      
#>  8 Charlotte  Carolinas Healthcare System, Charlotte, North Carolina, USA                          
#>  9 Cleveland  University Hospitals Case Medical Center; Seidman Cancer Center, Cleveland, Ohio, USA
#> 10 Nashville  Vanderbilt University Medical Center, Nashville, Tennessee, USA                      
#> 11 Seattle    Seattle Cancer Care Alliance, Seattle, Washington, USA                               
#> 12 Goyang-si  National Cancer Center, Gyeonggi-do, Korea, Republic of                              
#> 13 서울특별시 Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of                        
#> 14 Seoul      Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea,  Republic of       
#> 15 Seoul      Korea University Guro Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of                            
#> 16 Seoul      Asan Medical Center., Seoul, Korea, Republic of                                      
#> 17 Amsterdam  VU MEDISCH CENTRUM; Dept. of Medical Oncology
```

...well, it's not perfect. The biggest issue is that cities are classified as `localities` for US cities, but `administrative_area_level_1` (which in the US is the state) for South Korea. Unlike the other Korean rows, 12 actually has a locality, which is not the city listed (which is in the response as an administrative region). Further, "Seoul" in line 13 was inexplicably translated to Korean.

The good news is that "Saint Louis" has been shortened to "St. Louis", which is a more standardized form, and the last row has been located in Amsterdam.

Scaling such an approach would likely require paying Google a little for the usage of their API.

Comment: The Google geocoding API has a free tier (I have been using it for years), so if the OP wants to use it occasionally for research purposes then he need not pay anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit` and `sub`:

```
terms <- unlist(strsplit(test, "\\s*\\|\\s*"))
cities <- sapply(terms, function(x) gsub("[^,]+,\\s*([^,]+),.*", "\\1", x))
cities[1:3]

            Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA 
                                                "San Diego" 
            Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA 
                                                "New Haven" 
Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA
                                                   "Boston"
```

### Demo

Comment: nice apporach but test includes just 1 of the 25 text that i want to check  and for some reason it does not work in a for loop unlike @Onyambu solution.

Comment: How does it know where is city? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
test2 <- str_replace_all(test, "[|]", ", ") #Same as you did

test3 <- unlist(strsplit(test2, split=", ")) #Turns string into a vector

check <- test3 %in% world.cities$name #Check if element vectors match list of city names

test3[check == TRUE] #Select vector elements that match list of city names

 [1] "San Diego"   "New Haven"   "Boston"      "Boston"      "Saint Louis" "New York"    "New York"    "New York"   
 [9] "New York"    "Charlotte"   "Cleveland"   "Nashville"   "Seattle"     "Washington"
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @hrbrmstr's comment above, you can use the Stanford CoreNLP library to do named entity recognition (NER) on each string. The big caveat to such an undertaking is that most NER annotators only go so far as to annotate a token as a "location" or equivalent, which is not very useful when cities are mixed in with states and countries. Beyond its usual NER annotator, though, CoreNLP does contain an extra regex NER annotator that can increase NER granularity to the level of cities.

In R, you can use the `coreNLP` package to run the annotators. It does require `rJava`, which in some cases can be hard to configure. You'll also need to download the actual (pretty big) library, which can be done with `coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP`, and, should you like, set the `CORENLP_HOME` environment variable in `~/.Renviron` to the installation path.

Also note that this approach is fairly slow and resource-intensive, as it's doing a lot of work in Java.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(coreNLP)

# set which annotators to use
writeLines('annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner\n', 'corenlp.properties')
initCoreNLP(libLoc = Sys.getenv('CORENLP_HOME'), parameterFile = 'corenlp.properties')
unlink('corenlp.properties')    # clean up

places <- data_frame(string = "Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA|Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA|Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Dana Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Washington University, Saint Louis, Missouri, USA|Mount SInai Medical Center, New York, New York, USA|Memorial Sloan Kettering Cancer Center, New York, New York, USA|Carolinas Healthcare System, Charlotte, North Carolina, USA|University Hospitals Case Medical Center; Seidman Cancer Center, Cleveland, Ohio, USA|Vanderbilt University Medical Center, Nashville, Tennessee, USA|Seattle Cancer Care Alliance, Seattle, Washington, USA|National Cancer Center, Gyeonggi-do, Korea, Republic of|Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Korea University Guro Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Asan Medical Center., Seoul, Korea, Republic of|VU MEDISCH CENTRUM; Dept. of Medical Oncology") %>% 
    separate_rows(string, sep = '\\|')    # separate strings

places_ner <- places %>% 
    mutate(annotations = map(string, annotateString),
           tokens = map(annotations, 'token'), 
           tokens = map(tokens, group_by, token_id = data.table::rleid(NER)), 
           city = map(tokens, filter, NER == 'CITY'), 
           city = map(city, summarise, city = paste(token, collapse = ' ')), 
           city = map_chr(city, ~if(nrow(.x) == 0) NA_character_ else .x$city))
```

which returns

```
places_ner %>% select(city, string)
#> # A tibble: 17 x 2
#>    city      string                                                                               
#>    <chr>     <chr>                                                                                
#>  1 San Diego Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA                                      
#>  2 New Haven Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA                                      
#>  3 Boston    Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA                          
#>  4 Boston    Dana Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, Massachusetts, USA                             
#>  5 NA        Washington University, Saint Louis, Missouri, USA                                    
#>  6 NA        Mount SInai Medical Center, New York, New York, USA                                  
#>  7 NA        Memorial Sloan Kettering Cancer Center, New York, New York, USA                      
#>  8 Charlotte Carolinas Healthcare System, Charlotte, North Carolina, USA                          
#>  9 Cleveland University Hospitals Case Medical Center; Seidman Cancer Center, Cleveland, Ohio, USA
#> 10 Nashville Vanderbilt University Medical Center, Nashville, Tennessee, USA                      
#> 11 Seattle   Seattle Cancer Care Alliance, Seattle, Washington, USA                               
#> 12 NA        National Cancer Center, Gyeonggi-do, Korea, Republic of                              
#> 13 Seoul     Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of                        
#> 14 Seoul     Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea, Republic of       
#> 15 Seoul     Korea University Guro Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of                            
#> 16 Seoul     Asan Medical Center., Seoul, Korea, Republic of                                      
#> 17 NA        VU MEDISCH CENTRUM; Dept. of Medical Oncology
```

Failings:

- "New York" is recognized twice as a state or province ("New York City" would be recognized as such).
- "Saint Louis" is recognized as a person. "St. Louis" is recognized as a location on my installation, but [an online version of the same library](http://corenlp.run/) recognizes the original as a location, so this may be a version issue.
- "Gyeonggi-do" isn't recognized, though "Seoul" is. I'm not sure how granular the `regexner` annotator goes, but given (as the name suggests) it works by regex, there is a size/familiarity threshold under which it doesn't contain a regex. [You can add your own regex to it](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html) if it's worthwhile, though.

The [`cleanNLP` package](https://github.com/statsmaths/cleanNLP) also supports Stanford CoreNLP (and a couple other backends) with an easier-to-use interface (setup is still hard), but as far as I can tell doesn't allow the use of `regexner` at the moment due to how it initializes CoreNLP.

Comment: Note to users who try the above code: The CITY NER-filter is not available in coreNLP 3.6.0 (from Jan 2016) which the `coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP()` command still downloads (on my machine, in April 2018) by default.  You can download newer models from the coreNLP homepage https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html.  v3.9.1 is more difficult to configure , it needs ~10GB of swap space for instance

Comment: The above was with 3.7.0, though it looks like [city NER with RegexNER is still arranged the same in 3.9.1.](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/regexner.html)

Comment: this is great! do you know of NER for more languages (like Hebrew)

Comment: [CoreNLP does support more languages](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html), but not Hebrew yet. [Other Hebrew NLP tools are in development](https://github.com/iddoberger/awesome-hebrew-nlp), though; one may fit your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tidytext to extract bigram--> words --> intersect to get the common part

```
library(tidyverse)
libraty(tidytext)
# city is a vector containing pre-defined city name
t2 <- test %>% as_tibble() %>% 
unnest_tokens(bigram,value,token = 'ngrams', n =2) %>% 
separate(bigram,c('word1','word2'),remove = F) 

city_get <- c(intersect(t2$bigram,city),intersect(t2$word1,city))%>%
            unique()
```